# Checked checkboxes only for the users in a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, many-to-many

In my database I have two tables that has a many-to-many relationship, and by that reason I've created a relationship table.

```
Projects
Users
Project_users <-- members of a project
```

I'm working on the view for editing a project, which contain of a form with all the project fields, and for the members of a project I render out checkboxes. This works, but with the code below all the checkboxes is checked, even for the users that's not members of the project.

So, how should I change the code so only the checkboxes for the current members of the project gets checked?

**edit project view:**

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    ...
        the rest of the form
    ...
    <div class="checkbox">
        <% @members.each do |user| %>
            <%= check_box_tag "project[members][]", user.id, '1', :id => "user_#{user.id}" %> 
            <%= label_tag "user_#{user.id}", user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name, :class => "checkbox" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    ...
        the rest of the form
    ...
<% end %>
```

**projects controller:**

```
...
def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @members = @project.users
end
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to the `check_box_tag` is the boolean for the check(ed) state:

See the doc:  [`check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

In your case:

```
<% should_be_checked = @project.users.include?(user) %>
<%= check_box_tag "project[members][]", user.id, should_be_checked, :id => "user_#{user.id}" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tried it out and got the following error: .../edit.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected '='
       should_be_checked? = project.users.include?(user)

Comment: It worked after I added a '@' to project.users... (@project.users...) and changed to User.all in the controller. Thanks alot!